# Eclipse Template for a method to add an element to collection

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I have a pojo class with a collection field:

```
public class MyObject {
    private List<String> someNames = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

Now I want to create an Eclipse Template to generate a method for adding elements to the collection, like generating getters and setters. The created method should look like this:

```
public void addSomeName(String someName) {
    this.someNames.add(someName);
}
```

The parameter name should be the singular name of the collection. The method name should be "add" + the capitalized parameter name. The template should also show a proposal list for possible collections, like the default while-iterator-template.

Is it possible to create a template for this method?

My current attempt is this, but there is no proposal list, no replacement for the parameter type and this parameter name isn't created:

```
public void add${elem:newName(col)}(${type:elemType(col)} ${elem}) {
    this.${col:field(java.util.Collection)}.add(${elem});
}
```

Comment: Info: I think, it is not possible with Eclipse. There is also this 14 years old bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12756